# Unable to animate gradient layer for shimmer in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cabasicanimation

Unable to animate gradient layer using CABasicAnimation for shimmer.

```
CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { UIColor.Black.CGColor, UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha(0.1F).CGColor, UIColor.Black.CGColor };
gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.0, 0.525);
gradientLayer.Locations = new NSNumber[] { 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 };
gradientLayer.Frame = new CGRect(- shimmerView.Frame.Width, 0, 3 * shimmerView.Frame.Width, shimmerView.Frame.Height);

shimmerView.Layer.Mask = gradientLayer;

CABasicAnimation anmtn = new CABasicAnimation();
anmtn.KeyPath = "TransGrad";
anmtn.From = NSArray.FromObjects(new NSNumber[] { 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 });
anmtn.To = NSArray.FromObjects(new NSNumber[] { 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 });
anmtn.Duration = 2;
anmtn.RepeatCount = 1000;
gradientLayer.AddAnimation(animation, "loc");
```

I'm able to animate using the same logic in swift. Please provide your answers for Xamarin.iOS.

Swift

```
let light = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
let dark = UIColor.black.cgColor
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [dark, light, dark]
gradient.frame = CGRect(x: -self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: 3 * self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.525)
gradient.locations = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
self.layer.mask = gradient

let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
animation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]
animation.toValue = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

animation.duration = 1.5
animation.repeatCount = HUGE
gradient.add(animation, forKey: "shimmer")
```

Comment: What's the code for this logic in Swift?

Comment: @adlee-dev Updated the post. Please check

Comment: You don't seem to be setting anmtn.To at all in the C# code.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake happened while pasting the code in stackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the value you are passing to `KeyPath` for your animation. `CAGradientLayer` does not have a property `TransGrad` so attempting to add an animation with that KeyPath will not work.

If you just keep the same key path from the Swift version, the animation should behave the same:

```
CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { UIColor.Black.CGColor, UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha(0.1F).CGColor, UIColor.Black.CGColor };
gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.0, 0.525);
gradientLayer.Locations = new NSNumber[] { 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 };
gradientLayer.Frame = new CGRect(- shimmerView.Frame.Width, 0, 3 * shimmerView.Frame.Width, shimmerView.Frame.Height);

shimmerView.Layer.Mask = gradientLayer;

CABasicAnimation anmtn = new CABasicAnimation();
anmtn.KeyPath = "locations";
anmtn.From = NSArray.FromObjects(new NSNumber[] { 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 });
anmtn.To = NSArray.FromObjects(new NSNumber[] { 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 });
anmtn.Duration = 2;
anmtn.RepeatCount = 1000;
gradientLayer.AddAnimation(anmtn, "shimmer");
```

Note that it's `"locations"` and not `"Locations"` because this value ultimately gets passed to native iOS libraries so the case must match how the property is named there.

If this doesn't fix your issue, you'll need to provide more information on what `shimmerView` in your C# code and `self` in your Swift code are and the contexts which these code snippets are called.